# Sharing vscode cache between different machines

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to code in cloud environments and using the Remote SSH extensions to support that:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-edit

However, I am curious if it is possible to share VSCode cache between the different environments.

The way my work is set up is:

- I can create an indefinite amount of new environments in the cloud that I can SSH into;
- These machines have the exact same files on it.

Every time I create a new machine, the VSCode cache seems to be busted and the file system and the Intellisense features (such as type checks/code navigation) need to reindex/rebuild cache (I am guessing).

Since the file system is huge, the reindex takes a long time and since the machines are identical, I'd like to see if the cache of one machine could be reused for the other machines to speed up vscode file finder.

I have a feeling that the cache is partly host-name dependent, and seems to be stored on the local machine (please correct me if I am wrong). If I delete a machine and recreate it with exactly the same host-name, the cache seems to partially work.

Is there a way to make sure that different hosts will be able to read the same VSCode cache? Perhaps some naming trickery?

The hosts are partially named the same `abcd.xyz.always-the-same.com`, so would it be possible to perhaps make the cache key from the `always-the-same.com` part?

Any advice on this would be super helpful!